Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager. React Native
I get this error when i click 'AppSettings' button
Node version: v18.20.3
Yarn version: 1.22.22
I tried so much things like, install pods after cleaning all cache and removing currents Pods and lock files.
And also upgrade and downgrade versions of same packages like @react-navigation/native, react-native-safe-area-context
**Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.
This error is located at:
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:92)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:46)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at NativeStackView.native.tsx:343)
    in NativeStackView (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:69)
    in Unknown (at createNativeStackNavigator.tsx:68)
    in NativeStackNavigator (at AppSettings.navigator.tsx:15)
    in AppSettingsNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:132)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:124)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:217)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (created by TabBarElement)
    in RNSScreen (at createAnimatedComponent.js:211)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:264)
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (at src/index.native.tsx:314)
    in Suspender (at src/index.tsx:40)
    in Suspense (at src/index.tsx:39)
    in Freeze (at src/index.native.tsx:206)
    in DelayedFreeze (at src/index.native.tsx:313)
    in InnerScreen (at src/index.native.tsx:566)
    in Screen (created by ResourceSavingScene)
    in ResourceSavingScene (created by TabBarElement)
    in RNSScreenContainer (at src/index.native.tsx:400)
    in ScreenContainer (created by TabBarElement)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (created by TabBarElement)
    in TabBarElement (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (at App.tsx:78)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:430)
    in BaseNavigationContainer (at NavigationContainer.tsx:132)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:131)
    in NavigationContainerInner (at App.tsx:77)
    in Observer (at App.tsx:75)
    in App (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:92)
    in RCTView (at View.js:32)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:119)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:43)
    in WaCon(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:60)
 LOG  BleManagerDiscoverPeripheral listener removed!
 LOG  BleManagerStopScan listener removed!
 LOG  BleManagerDisconnectPeripheral listener removed!
 LOG  BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic listener removed!
 LOG  BleManagerDidUpdateState listener removed!
Error: Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS from /Users/menduhcaylak/Desktop/furkan/wacon/node_modules/react-native/index.js: 
None of these files exist:
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS/index(.native|.native.js|.js|.native.json|.json|.native.ts|.ts|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  15 | import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
  16 | import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
> 17 | import typeof DatePickerIOS from './Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS';
     |                                   ^
  18 | import typeof DrawerLayoutAndroid from './Libraries/Components/DrawerAndroid/DrawerLayoutAndroid';
  19 | import typeof FlatList from './Libraries/Lists/FlatList';
  20 | import typeof Image from './Libraries/Image/Image';


My package.json
{
  "name": "wacon",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "postinstall": "npx jetify"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.2",
    "@types/sync-storage": "^0.4.3",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "convert-string": "^0.1.0",
    "css-to-react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "mobx": "^6.5.0",
    "mobx-react": "^7.3.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.4",
    "react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^8.0.2",
    "react-native-country-flag": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.5.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.14.1",
    "react-native-location": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-paper-dates": "^0.8.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "3.29.0",
    "react-native-scroll-wheel-picker": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-view-slider": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-wheel-scrollview-picker": "^2.0.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "sync-storage": "^0.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.8",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/convert-string": "^0.1.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.15",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}

My App.tsx:
import * as React from 'react';
import MyDevicesScreen from './src/scenes/MyDevices.screen';
import appStore from './src/shared/stores/App.store';
import IconFeather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
import IconMaterial from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import DropdownAlert from 'react-native-dropdownalert';
import deviceHelper from './src/shared/helpers/Device.helper';

import {SettingsStackNavigator} from './src/navigations/SettingsStack.navigator';
import {Alert, useEffect} from 'react-native';
import {EventArg, NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {BottomTabScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {AnimatedTabBarNavigator} from 'react-native-animated-nav-tab-bar';
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';
import {navigationRef} from './src/shared/helpers/RootNavigation.helper';
import {translate} from './src/services/translations';
import configStore from './src/shared/stores/Configs.store';
import {observer, Observer} from 'mobx-react';
import {AppSettingsNavigator} from './src/navigations/AppSettings.navigator';
import {getData} from './src/shared/stores/Storage.store';

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

type BottomTabScreenParamList = {
  MyDevices: undefined;
  DeviceSettings: undefined;
  Profiles: undefined;
  AppSettings: undefined;
};

type Props = BottomTabScreenProps<BottomTabScreenParamList, 'MyDevices'>;

const Tabs = AnimatedTabBarNavigator();

const App = () => {
  function checkIsDeviceConnected(
    e: EventArg<string, true, undefined>,
    navigation: Props['navigation'],
  ) {
    if (!appStore.isConnected) {
      // Prevent default behavior
      e.preventDefault();
      Alert.alert(translate('alert'), translate('no_device_connected_2'), [
        {
          text: translate('okay'),
          onPress: () => {
            if (appStore.isConnected) {
              navigation.navigate('MyDevices');
            }
          },
        },
      ]);
    } else {
      deviceHelper.getAllSettings();
    }
  }

  const TabBarIcon = (props: any) => {
    return props.fontName === 'feather' ? (
      <IconFeather
        name={props.name}
        size={props.size ? props.size : 24}
        color={props.tintColor}
      />
    ) : props.fontName === 'material' ? (
      <IconMaterial
        name={props.name}
        size={props.size ? props.size : 24}
        color={props.tintColor}
      />
    ) : null;
  };

  return (
    <Observer>
      {() => (
        <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
          <Tabs.Navigator
            initialRouteName="MyDevices"
            tabBarOptions={{
              activeTintColor: '#2F7C6E',
              inactiveTintColor: '#222222',
            }}
            appearance={{
              shadow: true,
              floating: false,
            }}>
            <Tabs.Screen
              name={'MyDevices'}
              component={MyDevicesScreen}
              options={{
                title: translate('my_devices'),
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
                  <TabBarIcon
                    focused={focused}
                    fontName="feather"
                    tintColor={color}
                    name="search"
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
              name={'DeviceSetttings'}
              component={SettingsStackNavigator}
              listeners={({navigation}) => ({
                tabPress: e => {
                  checkIsDeviceConnected(e, navigation);
                },
              })}
              options={{
                title: translate('device_settings'),
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
                  <TabBarIcon
                    focused={focused}
                    fontName="material"
                    tintColor={color}
                    name="timer-cog-outline"
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />
            <Tabs.Screen
              name={'AppSetttings'}
              component={AppSettingsNavigator}
              listeners={({navigation}) => ({
                tabPress: () => {
                  navigation.navigate('PhoneSettings');
                },
              })}
              options={{
                title: translate('app_settings'),
                tabBarIcon: ({focused, color}) => (
                  <TabBarIcon
                    focused={focused}
                    fontName="feather"
                    tintColor={color}
                    name="settings"
                  />
                ),
              }}
            />
          </Tabs.Navigator>
          <DropdownAlert
            closeInterval={700}
            ref={ref => {
              if (ref) {
                appStore.setDropDownAlertRef(ref);
              }
            }}
          />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </Observer>
  );
};

export default App;


My AppSettingsNavigator.navigator.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import PhoneSettings from '../scenes/PhoneSettings.screen';
import PhoneInfo from '../scenes/PhoneInfo.screen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const screenOptionStyle = {
  headerShown: false,
};

const AppSettingsNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptionStyle}>
      <Stack.Screen name="PhoneSettings" component={PhoneSettings} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PhoneInfo" component={PhoneInfo} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export {AppSettingsNavigator};


My PhoneSettings.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import Header from '../components/Header.component';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import {NavigationProp, ParamListBase} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {translate} from '../services/translations';

const AppSettings = ({
  navigation,
}: {
  navigation: NavigationProp<ParamListBase>;
}) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Header onBackPress={navigation.goBack} />
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('PhoneInfo');
          }}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Icon size={50} name={'cellphone-information'} color={'#019267'} />
            <Text style={styles.buttonLabels}>
              {translate('phone_settings')}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 25,
  },
  buttonLabels: {
    paddingLeft: 30,
    fontSize: 23,
  },
  scrollStyle: {
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});
export default AppSettings;


Output of npx react-native info:
System:
    OS: macOS 13.7.2
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz
    Memory: 46.97 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.20.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.22 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.8.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.3/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.16.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 23.2, iOS 17.2, macOS 14.2, tvOS 17.2, visionOS 1.0, watchOS 10.2
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2024.1 AI-241.15989.150.2411.11948838
    Xcode: 15.2/15C500b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: javac 17 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ^17.0.2 => 17.0.2 
    react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found

